# Why is the conjunction 'que' used in 'Yo digo que sí'?

Tags: gramática, conjunciones

Why is the conjunction "que" used in this sentence?

> Yo digo que sí.

I'm trying to understand the grammar behind the conjunction use. I'm thinking it is mandatory in Spanish structures (while in English it can be omitted)?

Comment: Good guess.  Yes, it's omitted much less in Spanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike in English, where the conjunction "que" can be omitted in reported speech, in Spanish it is almost always required. Otherwise, what follows the reporting verb will be interpreted as direct speech:

- Yo digo "sí".

"Yo digo que sí" is equivalent to the English pattern "I say (that) + subject + auxiliary":

> A: ¿Es la persona indicada? (Is he the right person?)
>
> B: Yo digo que sí. (I say he is.)

---

> A: ¿Ella lo mató? (Did she kill him?)
>
> B: Yo digo que sí. (I say she did.)

---

> A: ¿Vas a venir? (Will you come?)
>
> B: Yo digo que sí. (I say I will.)

Comment: The reason behing it is a verb ellipsis:  "yo digo que sí (quiero)".

Comment: There is no that in English to translate the two Spanish uses of digo que sí. And there is no reported speech here in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

A la pergunta: **¿Qué dices?** se puede decir: Digo que sí.

Es una respuesta a la pregunta.

**También puede ser enfático**: Digo que sí, hombre. Quiero asistir a la fiesta.

A la pergunta: ¿Como votas? [por ejemplo] Digo sí.

Digo sí [a la independencia, por ejemplo].

[ejemplo de decir sí](https://www.newdeal.es/blog/productividad/decir-si-o-decir-no/)

Decir sí o no en relación a un asunto.

**Decir sí, o decir no?**

¿Puedes venir un momento? ¿Me echas una mano? ¿Puedes mirarte esto? ¿Tienes un minuto? …
**Sí, sí, sí, por supuesto que sí, ¡faltaría más!**
¿Te has fijado?, ¡siempre decimos que sí! [dicho con énfasis]

[decir que sí, decir sí](https://www.eldiario.es/andalucia/desdeelsur/digo-independencia_6_691940804.html)

The que is used for two reasons: one is emphasis on the yes: I'm **saying** yes. or it is a response to ¿Qué dices? Digo que sí.

It is not mandatory and it has zero do do with English.

I say yes (normal response) versus the emphatic: I'm saying yes. In English  that would not be used here for the two uses  in Spanish.